# SFTP to /mnt/ folder in Google Compute Engine, Allow user to write

Tags: google-compute-engine, sftp

I have a Google Compute Engine and mounted an extra storage. This mount has a directory `/mnt/`. I am sending over files in the folder via SFTP. I provided an account for the uploader.

The uploader does not see the `/mnt/` folder via SFTP. I tried using WinSCP in the uploader to see the folders but the folder is not there.

How chan I allow write persmission to the user to see and write in that folder?

Comment: Can I know if winscp is installed inside the GCP VM and you are trying to send the files to /mnt/? Where does this /mnt/ is located either in the same GCP VM itself or any other linux server?

Comment: `/mnt/` is insite the GCP VM. WinSCP is installed in my uploader which is the one trying to transfer files from. `/mnt/` is a additional disk installed for a GCP VM not included with the system storage

Comment: Check the owner and directory permissions for the mount point. Then use commands like `chown` and `chmod` to set file/directory permissions or use commands like `usermod` to add the user to the group. Without details, recommending the a strategy and commands to execute would be guesses which can cause security problems. Find someone who understands basic Linux administration to help you.

Comment: As John Hanley suggested : Check the permissions of the /mnt/ folder by running the following command in the Compute Engine terminal: `ls -l` or `ls -la /mnt/`  and also Check if it is not having necessary permissions to access the /mnt/ folder, you can grant them write permission by running the following command in the terminal: `sudo chmod u+w /mnt/`. Refer to this [Permissions doc](https://www.howtogeek.com/437958/how-to-use-the-chmod-command-on-linux/) by DAVE MCKAY how to check and give the read, write permissions.

Comment: @Nikko : Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.